# rails, how to pass a variable from a link_to helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, link-to

in my routes.rb i have

```
match "monsters/:category" => "monsters#index"
```

i have a bunch of links such as

- Water
- Fire
- Earth
- Flying

however im having trouble passing "Water" or "Fire" as the :category for my routes.
how exactly do i do that?

i tried something like...

```
<%= link_to "Water", "monsters/water"(:category => "water") %>
```

but syntactically i cant do that. how do i pass in "water" as the :category symbol?

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to specify :`category` in the **link_to**. While doing this:

```
<%= link_to "Water", "monsters/water" %>
```

Your routes will match water to the `:category` parameter, and therefore in your controller you can access `params[:category]` and **water** will be the value.  Notice that in the routes you are already saying that whatever comes after the "monsters/" will be recognized as the category parameter.

Notice that if you have [Named Routes](http://railscasts.com/episodes/34-named-routes), you can pass parameters like this:

```
<%= link_to "Up", monster_path(:category => "water") %>
```